# Dropdown not fixed to input field on scroll

Tags: javascript, flexdatalist

I have an annoying problem with flexadatalist. If I open dropdown, then move a mouse outside of an element and start to scroll, the input field scrolls but dropdown stays fixed. It is really annoying and really bad user experience. So far I've researched two possible options.

**1. Option**
Block background scrolling on an flexdatalist event. Problem: there is no event, or at least I haven't found it, to call, when dropdown opens. There is `shown:flexdatalist.results` but that is called for each and every option in a dropdown. Or `after:flexdatalist.data` but that also hasn't done the trick.

**2. Option**
Use JS or Jquery on click event to block scrolling on everything except in flexdatalist dropdown. Problem: cannot be used as a global solution as it has to be styled occasionally. Means if I open modal with flexdatalist I have to block scrolling in modal or if I open it on a body, then body has to be blocked, etc.

If anybody knows a solution that could be used as a global solution please let me know, I'm a little bit stuck. Thx

**WORKAROUND**
I finally found a workaround that solved this. Not a best practice but it works.
Step1: On `show:flexdatalist.results` I am setting overflow to hidden, not in dropdown of course.
Step 2: If something is selected then on `change:flexdatalist` I am restoring overflow.
Step 3: Because there is no event if dropdown is closed and nothing is selected, I've simply used `$(document).on('click', function () {...}` to also restore overflow.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you are describing using any of the examples found under http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/ So you should first of all show a [mre] that actually shows the issue.

Comment: We are using flexdatalist on an extended user portal. It is not possible to recreate the whole thing just to be tested separately and unfortunately I also cannot share a link. So that is the best thing I can do. I am not saying that it is a bug, we just have this problem. Maybe someone also had the same experience or can share one or two ideas how this could be solved.